# Как сделать раскрывающийся список внутри таблицы не правя html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, список

Есть табличка с перечнем товаров. Хочу сделать раскрывающийся список при нажатии на `+` отдельно для каждого товара. Как это можно сделать не вмешиваясь в структуру `html` ? Загвоздка в том, что количество товаров и наименований в нем может быть различным без ограничений. Пока раскрывает только 1 элемент после названия товара.

```js
 $('.plus').click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.order').next('.order_item').toggle();
 });
```

```css
.order_item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="order-count">
  <tr class="order">
    <td>Товар 1 <span class="plus">+</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="order_item">
    <td>Наименование 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="order_item">
    <td>Наименование 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="order">
    <td>Товар 2 <span class="plus">+</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="order_item">
    <td>Наименование 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать реализовать это через

```
 $('.plus').click(function() {
      $(this).parents('.order').nextUntil(".order",'.order_item').toggle();
  });
```

Будет раскрывать все между двумя `.order` если я не ошибаюсь

[fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2hEJ/9/)

Comment: в принципе `each` не нужен, можно сразу `toggle` звать

Comment: @Grundy спасибо , обновил